# How to prevent search input name from displaying

Tags: javascript, html

I am relatively new and learning the ropes. The code below works properly, but I do not know how to prevent the search input name from displaying on page. Image also attached below. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
<h1>Enter Name</h1>
<form method="get">
    <p>
        <label for="requestName">Enter Your Name:</label>
        <input type="search" name="nameEntered" id="nameEntered">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    n=document.location.search.substring(0);
    document.write("<h3>")

    n1=document.location.search.substring(1);

    n2=new Array();
    n2=n1.split('&');

    document.write("You entered the name " + n2[0]);
    document.write("</h3>")
</script>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Delete or comment-out this line:  `document.write("You entered the name " + n2[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

Any `document.write()` functions will essentially, write to the HTML document on the client side. So as you can see from your code, it is writing a `<h3>` opening and closing tag, and also `"You have entered the name " + n2[0]`.

Remove those, and you won't have any data written to the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can further split the result string to remove name as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    n=document.location.search.substring(0);
    document.write("<h3>")

    n1=document.location.search.substring(1);

    n2=new Array();
    n2=n1.split('&');

    n3=new Array();
    n3=n2[0].split('=');

    document.write("You entered the name " + n3[1]);
    document.write("</h3>")
</script>
```

you can add "=" or ":" if like as:

```
document.write("You entered the name: " + n3[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>Enter Name</h1>
<form method="get">
    <p>
        <label for="requestName">Enter Your Name:</label>
        <input type="search" name="nameEntered" id="nameEntered">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    n=document.location.search.substring(0);
    document.write("<h3>")

    n1=document.location.search.substring(1);

    n2=new Array();
    n2=n1.split('&');
    var x = n2[0].split('=');
    document.write("You entered the name " + x[1]);
    document.write("</h3>")
</script>
```

Try This it should do the job.